# Layer drawing order

Tags: openlayers

I have a map with various vector layers, and I would like to be able to decide which layer goes on top of which. I thought that inserting the layers in the map layer group using:

```
map.getLayers().insertAt(zIndex, layer);
```

would force the layers to be drawn in that specific order, but that does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any other code?

Comment: That should work @GabrielePallaver.  I'm guessing you've got another problem that we're not able to see without you sharing additional code...